# Popup is NOT getting recognized in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have Button in WebPage Add Remarks. On Click of button, it opens the pop up whereas you can enter the message.

While Running the script, it clicks the button and pop up is shown.. But if i use Displayed method to verify, it returns false.

I have used Thread.Sleep for 5 to 10 seconds (which is more than enough) but still it is keep on waiting and getting Timedout exception.

```
<div class="modal fade in" data-backdrop="false" data-keyboard="false" id="showAddRemarksPopUp" pagetitle="Add Remarks" visible="showAddRemarks" style="display: block; padding-right: 17px;">
```

How to change the control to popup??

Comment: is that pop is an alert which takes some text if yes then try Alert alt = driver.switchTo().alert();
  alt.sendKeys("your text " ); if its still a pop up then plz look if that pop up is inside a iframe

Comment: It is not an alert or frame since it returns getWindowhandles count is 1.

Comment: ok but i guess getWindowhandles is used to count windows not i frames for frames to count plz use like   List<WebElement> allIframe = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
  System.out.println("Count of i-frame is : " + allIframe.size()); // if greater then 0 then i frame is present

Comment: It is returning zero..

Comment: ok strange can you plz upload the exception message that you are getting also html source code

Comment: if driver.switchTo().alert() is not works, than u have to switch on your pop up box using the pop up box element locator. In ur case, what is the locator of pop up box textbox? first click() on that, than use sendkeys()

Comment: It is not even finding the pop up to change the control